# Data format for calling an AWS SageMaker object detection model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained an object detection model in AWS SageMaker and created an endpoint for it. The endpoint is called via a lambda function that is accessed through an api gateway. So far so good.

Now I want to call the api from an angular application - upload a picture and get back the predictions. But I am having trouble figuring out the correct way to do it. The aws documentation I've seen so far doesn't go into much detail on that part.

I got the image as a blob, captured from an html canvas. I tried to convert the blob to a byte array:

```
    fileReader.onload = function () {
    arrayBuffer = this.result;

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    that.http.post<any>(that.url, byteArray.toString(), {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-Api-Key', that.apiKey).set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    }).toPromise().then((result) => {
      resolve(result);
    });
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

The response is:

```
{"message":"Received client error (400) from model with message \"unable to evaluate payload provided\".}
```

Has anyone done this yet? What is the correct way to submit an image?

Thank you.

Comment: The API gateway you mentioned is providing an HTTP endpoint?
When I did it, I had a Flask app running and it called the SageMaker Endpoint. So the frontend app should call the flask endpoint.

Comment: The reason for the lambda function and the api gateway was that the sagemaker endpoint does not support cors (yet?). I think this is a valid approach.

But I am still struggling with sending my image from my angular frontend.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't (AFAIK). So, you can try to deploy a small Flask application in AWS to call the endpoint using Boto3.

Comment: But even then I still need to figure out how to send the picture to the flask endpoint. I think switching from api gateway + lambda function to flask doesn't solve my problem or am I missing something?

Comment: We send it as a URL and the flask application downloads the image. So make sure that you can get a URL for your image which the flask application can access.